# React's setState is only selectively updating state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-native-modal-datetime-picker per its docs. I'm trying to save the date (which is appearing in a console log inside the handleStartDatePicked function) as this.state.startDateTime. I'm attempting to do this by using React's setState, but it's not working. Out of curiosity, I've tried changing another property (in the below example 'startDateTimeNew') and this is correctly updating. I'm at a loss as to why the intended variable 'startDateTime' won't update.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import moment from 'moment';

class SessionScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'View Session',
  };

  state = {
    details: '',
    endDateTime: '',
    endDateTimePickerVisible: false,
    startDateTime: '',
    startDateTimePickerVisible: false,
  };

  handleEndDatePicked = (date) => {
    console.log('A date has been picked: ', date);
    this.hideEndDateTimePicker();
  };

  handleInputChangeFor = (propertyName,text) => {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        [propertyName]: text,
    });
    console.log('this.state:',this.state);
  }

  handleStartDatePicked = (date) => {
    console.log('A date has been picked: ', date, 'formatted:', moment(date).format('dddd[,] MMM Do h:mm A'));
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        startDateTimeNew: date.toString(),
        startDateTime: date.toString(),
    }, function() {
        console.log('new state',this.state);
    });
    console.log('this.state:', this.state);
    this.hideStartDateTimePicker();
  };

  hideEndDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ ...this.state, endDateTimePickerVisible: false });

  hideStartDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ ...this.state, startDateTimePickerVisible: false });

  showEndDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ ...this.state, endDateTimePickerVisible: true });

  showStartDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ ...this.state, startDateTimePickerVisible: true });

  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>START TIME</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showStartDateTimePicker} style={styles.touchableOpacity}>
          {/* <Text style={styles.touchableOpacityText}><this.dateTimeStart /></Text> */}
          <Text style={styles.touchableOpacityText}>Click to set start day and time</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.header}>END TIME</Text>
        <TextInput 
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Click to add end day and time..."
            returnKeyType="go"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            onChangeText={(input) => this.handleInputChangeFor('end',input)}
        />
        <Text style={styles.header}>DETAILS</Text>
        <TextInput 
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Enter details about this chill..."
            returnKeyType="go"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            onChangeText={(input) => this.handleInputChangeFor('details',input)}
        />
        <DateTimePicker
          isVisible={this.state.startDateTimePickerVisible}
          onConfirm={this.handleStartDatePicked}
          onCancel={this.hideStartDateTimePicker}
          mode={'datetime'}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#b2f6ff',
    padding: 10
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginBottom: 8,
    color: 'black',
    opacity: 0.8,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    width: 'auto'
  },
  touchableOpacity: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    width: 'auto',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  touchableOpacityText: {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
})

const mapReduxStateToProps = reduxState => (
  {reduxState}
);

export default connect(mapReduxStateToProps)(SessionScreen);
```

I've attempted setting the startDateTime both using date.toString() and moment(date).format('dddd[,] MMM Do h:mm A'. The date input to the function is an object, but successfully turns into a string with the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't determined why the setState won't work as it's written in the code from my question (especially since that setup works elsewhere in the file), however I've been able to find a workaround by setting state the following way:

```
let newState = this.state;
newState.startDateTime = date.toString();
this.setState(newState, function() {
    console.log('new state',this.state);
});
```

I still welcome any explanations that one may have about why the code in my question isn't successful.